# I want to generate random number in method once which are not same with previous one

Tags: javascript

I have to change background image in method. Background images are coming from this.items service but when method runs new background image shouldn't be same with previous one.
 When I run this method it changes images but new image can be same with previous one. How can I do?

```
export class GridManager {
    changeBackground() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").length);
        if (this.items[x].backgroundImage != "" && this.items[x].backgroundImage != null) {
            document.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundImage = `url('${this.items[x].backgroundImage}')`;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An easy approach would be to make an array with numbers up to `document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").length - 1`, and then remove random items until the array is empty. Then, regenerate the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value is in the array, if exist remove it or do whatever you need to do

```
function checkItem(array,checkItem){
    for( var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i] == checkItem){
           var removedItem= array.splice(checkItem,1); // your can remove it 
           /*or simply do your code here */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of solutions, to give you another one not mentioned here, you can do a custom generate random number that excludes the previous index that you got.

something like:

```
class GridManager {
     prevIndex = null;

     generateRandom(min, max, excludedIndex) {
          var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
          return (num === excludedIndex) ? this.generateRandom(min, max, excludedIndex) : num;
     }

     changeBackground() {
          var x = this.generateRandom(0, document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").length - 1, this.prevIndex);
          this.prevIndex = x;

          if (this.items[x].backgroundImage != "" && this.items[x].backgroundImage != null) {
              document.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundImage = `url('${this.items[x].backgroundImage}')`;
          }
    }
}
```